# Retain selected value after submit

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, postback

I have the following values in an array

```
<?php

$selectContact = 
array(
"Services Inquiry" => "Services", 
"Product Inquiry" => "Product", 
"Training Inquiry" => "Training", 
"Careers Inquiry" => "Careers", 
"General Inquiry" => "General"
);
?>
```

And calling the array in a dropdown list. When the form is submitted I need to retain the selected value of the dropdown menu.

```
<form role="select_contact" name="selectContact" id="selectContact">
                <select>
                    <!--<option value="Select">Select</option>-->
                    <option value="Select">Select</option>
                    <?php
                        if (isset($_POST['selectContact'])) {
                            echo '<option value="'. $value .'">' . $category . '</option>';

                        } else {
                            foreach($selectContact as $category => $value) 
                            {
                               $category = htmlspecialchars($category); 
                               echo '<option value="'. $value .'">'. $category .'</option>';
                            }
                        }
                    ?>

                </select>
            </form>
```

Comment: Use a ternary operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set `selected` property, like this:

```
<?php
    $selected = isset($_REQUEST['selectContact']) ? $_REQUEST['selectContact'] : '';
    foreach($selectContact as $category => $value) 
    {
        $category = htmlspecialchars($category); 
        echo '<option value="'. $value .'"'.(($value==$selected)?' selected':'').'>'. $category .'</option>';
    }
?>
```

NOTE: you don't need `if (isset($_POST['selectContact'])) {` branch at al